# Efficient way to drop the fractional part from float but retain the type

Tags: c++, floating-point

I know that by std::round, std::floor or std::ceil or simply typecasting we can drop the decimal part, but with typecasting,  the  the variable loses its original type ( float or double ).

Is there any way, I can retain the type and still drop the fractional part efficiently.

One of the method I thought was subtracting the fractional part from the number, but that isnt so efficient. So, maybe there are some other methods?

Example -

```
float a = 123.456;

float b;

b = do something on a;
```

result b is 123.0

Comment: Why can't you cast to an int then back to a float and let the compiler deal with it?

Comment: @MeetTitan That's all kinds of trouble. The range of a `float` is much bigger than `int`.

Comment: @MeetTitan `[conv.fpint]` "*A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type**.*"

Comment: `b = (int)a;` should do.

Comment: @melpomene, not in granularity.  If you take a 32bit floating point and try to assign it something like `1,000,000,123` to a 32bit integer lvalue, you probably get some surprise.... and that's well under the range of 32bit integer types.  In my case I got `1,000,000,128`, due to the lack of significand bits in the floating point, that are used in the integer counterpart. :)

Comment: @LuisColorado I agree with your last comment. But doesn’t the solution you propose in your earlier comment (`b = (int)a;`) suffer from exactly these problems?

Comment: @11684, you said _"from exactly these problems?"_  Exactly, what problems?  The ones about granularity? of course.  But it's difficult to cope with the whole range of a floating point number (that covers much more range than integer) and also be exact.  My comment tries to do the best possible and it does without calling library functions, as normally this is execute in one/two machine instructions (efficiently)  The solution `b = (int)a;` converts the number to `int` and then converts it again to floating point, dropping the fractional part.  You can loose bits in the way, unavoidably.

Comment: @LuisColorado I made a mistake in reasoning when writing my previous comment, but wouldn’t `float x = (int)x;` break down when representing values larger than INT_MAX?

Comment: Yes, and with `float` (32 bit) and `int` (also 32 bit)  you'll get different values as soon as you get well under `INT_MAX` (`float` only dedicates 24 bits to the significand --- 23 stored bits plus one `1` _implicit_ bit) so after `2**23`  you begin to round at even numbers, and multiples of 4 (on reaching `2**24`, and so on)  This is well under `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example, with `std::round` original type is preserved:

```
float round(float arg);
double round(double arg);
```

It is also true for `std::floor` and `std::ceil`.

**Addition.** Here are some benchmarking results.

```
Compiler     raw loop   std::ceil  std:floor  std::trunc  std::round
--------------------------------------------------------------------
gcc          8.36       8.20       8.19       8.21        32.95
gcc(f)       2.88       8.20       8.20       8.20        11.01
msvs         8.20       28.47      31.90      67.14       97.84
msvs(f)      8.13       13.70      14.00      67.27       97.50
```

Compilers: `gcc 7.3.0` and `msvs 2018 15.9.0`, machine: `Core i7-4770`.

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65bc02959811e950). Compilation options:

```
gcc: --std=c++17 -O3 -m64 -march=native -fno-tree-vectorize
gcc(f): --std=c++17 -O3 -m64 -march=native -ffast-math -fno-tree-vectorize
msvs: /fp:precise /fp:except /O2 /std:c++latest ...
msvs(f): /fp:fast /fp:except- /O2 /std:c++latest ...
```

Frankly speaking I don't think these results are very relevant (in the absolute values) on their own. With fast math option some functions reduce just to a single assembly instruction [`vroundss`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ROUNDSS.html). The real code should be profiled to get relevant results.

Comment: oh..that was simple.. Didnt know that round/floor/ceil retains the type. But makes sense.

Comment: This is actually the "greater" answer than the accepted one, IMO.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Why? It doesn't answer the question in the title (how to drop the fractional part of a number).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - well, the question was to efficiently drop the fractional part, coz the dataset where it will be used is huge. I did not benchmark, but I do strongly feel that trunc will win among the other contestants. Have changed ths subject line to be more specific.

Comment: @infoclogged please don't change your question after it's been answered; if you have a new question, ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Sneftel - its just improving the language. The original question and its answer remains valid.

Comment: @infoclogged, quick benchmark on my machine with MSVS 2018: `std::floor`, `std::trunc`, `std::round` - each next one is ~10% slower than the previous one.

Comment: @Evg - do you mind updating the answer with your benchmarks. if that is true, I will change my code from trunc to floor. Its strange that trunc is taking more time though, coz it needs to do further checks like negative values etc, whereas trunc simply drops the fractional part.

Comment: @Evg - thanks. the efficiency part was an important part and although I mentioned it twice in my question, it was missed in the answers. have changed the subject line since to be more specific. I will check for your post again tomorrow.

Comment: @melpemone: The question is/was: "but with typecasting, the the variable loses its original type ( float or double )." The other answer gave a solution with `modf`, but a simple `floor`, `ceil` or `trunc` will do too, and that is IMO the better answer. The OP thought the type would get lost, but the functions OP mentioned retain the type. Hence the better answer, IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [`modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf):

```
#include <cmath>

float a = 123.456;
float b, c;

c = std::modf(a, &b);
// c = 0.456
// b = 123.0
```

You don't have to use the return value (the fractional part) if you don't need it.

Or (since C++11) [`trunc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc):

```
float b = std::trunc(a);
```

Comment: great answer. Whats the difference of trunc and modf from round ( I now know, that round retains the type )?

Comment: @infoclogged `round` rounds to the nearest integer (away from 0), so e.g. `round(0.7)` is `1.0`, but `trunc(0.7)` is `0.0` (it just drops the fractional part).

Comment: it looks like trunc is really dumb and should be the fastest among all round, ceil, floor etc. this works for me.

Comment: @infoclogged: trunc() is not "dumb". It takes some work to convert an FP value to an integer value, the same kind of work as, say, for floor() or ceil(), or even round().

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Wouldn't you just have to set some bits of the mantissa to 0 (depending on the value of the exponent)?

Comment: @melpemone: Which bits/how many bits? But you don't set some bits to 0. you must know how many bits can be removed, then you must round to the last remaining bit position and then you must normalize the result. That is a little more work than just cutting off some bits. But usually this is one in hardware, so no big deal.

Comment: @melpomene, that's true (resetting some bits of the mantissa) only if you use ieee754 implementation.  You introduce a serious architecture dependency and possible U.B. in your code that way.  Exact bits to reset depend on the value to be truncated anyway.

Comment: @LuisColorado I think you're missing the point. I do not introduce any architecture dependency by using `std::trunc` in my code. What we're discussing is possible implementations of the standard library (which by their nature are implementation specific).

Comment: @melpomene, to discuss possible implementations, the one suggested by me is a valid one, you only have to take into account that the space of floating numbers extends beyond the space of integers.  I've tested at least CLANG implementation, and it returns 0 for out of range floating point numbers.  Anyway, you have the same exact problem with `std::trunc`, because you cannot modify the ranges involved, I'm afraid.  And you don't require a library function/macro.